# Bose Compact T1 Audio Recording on MacBook

Tags: audio-recording

I'm looking for the correct connection from the Bose Compact Stand T1 to my MacBook Pro (GarageBand) to capture sound from two microphones that are being projected by the Bose Stand.

On the Bose Compact T1:

main control board
[image: main control board]

From the main control board, microphone 1 gets plugged into the left "microphone" plug port. A wireless controller for microphone 2 gets plugged into main control board - the right "input" plug port.

Microphone 1 is a Shure wireless mic - so, from the "microphone" plug port, it connects to the "mic out" port:

[image: here]

and the back panel
[image: on the back]

What connection do I need to my MacBook in order to capture sound (using Garageband) from both microphones?

I've tried a male RCA to 3.5mm male headphone jack cable from the main control board to my MacBook, and also a male RCA to 3.5mm male headphone jack cable from the back panel to my Macbook. No dice.

The remaining options look like:

1. male RCA adapters from the back panel to USB MacBook
2. male RCA adapters from the main control board to USB MacBook
3. 1/4" stereo plug from the back panel to USB Macbook
4. Something else I don't know about?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you selected the proper input device in garageband? It might be set to use the internal microphone by default, you would need to select "line-in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Companies make inexpensive adapters that take an RCA input to USB.

As a note: the main panel is all inputs so you will not get a signal out of those RCA jacks. The only outputs are the ones on the back. I would suggest getting an RCA TO USB adapter.

Comment: Update: I bought RCA to USB connection and tried it, but the outputs still don't show up when connecting it to my Macbook. Essentially, nothing happens. Not sure if the RCA to USB has to be two pronged (red and white only to USB, or if its okay red/white/yellow to USB, and only use two prongs?)

Comment: @fronk no the red white yellow is the same as red and white. Maybe you need to select the USB device as the input source. Did you try that?

Comment: The USB device doesn't show up at all. I checked the "Sound" Preferences after plugging in the USB, and there were no new options.

Comment: @fronk that is interesting. Can you post a link to the one you bought? The only thing I can think is that it could be a one way converter and only works as a USB > RCA not RCA > USB. I don't know if those exist though.

Comment: Crap. It does say USB to RCA, however, I don't see that distinction being clearly made. Most other options look similar. Either way, it's too late. The event I needed it for happens tomorrow. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0748BW3X2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @fronk darn. Sorry man.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have selected the proper input device in Garageband. It might be set to use the Built-in webcam microphone by default, you would need to select "line-in". 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. The USB device doesn't show up at all under the MacBook "Sound" Preferences after plugging in the USB, so therefore, I don't think it'd show up in Garageband. Unless I'm wrong and it only shows up in Garageband, and not in the Sound pane, but that doesn't sound right.